# Generic method writing misunderstanding

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming, generic-collections

I'm currently writing a generics method to print the Key-Value pairs in a C# Dictionary; I figure its the best starting to point to get a grasp of the usefulness of this type of collection (as I did in Java with HashMaps).

There are two methods at work here:

```
ListWordCount(string text){// Code body}

// Returns a Dictionary<string, int> with the number of occurrences  
// Works exactly as intended (its from one of my textbooks)
```

And the problem method:

```
public static void PrintKeyValuePairs(Dictionary<IComparable, IComparable> dict)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<IComparable, IComparable> item in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        }

    }
// ... Some lines later
PrintKeyValuePairs( ListWordCount("Duck, duck, duck, goose") ); // Where we get the error
```

The current error that I'm being told is:

```
//"Argument 1: 
//Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, int>' to
//'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.IComparable,System.IComparable>'    "
```

.. Last I checked, both string and int implement 'IComparable', so I might be misunderstanding the inheritance nature, BUT I've done something very similar before that wasn't generics that worked. I would like to know how to correct for this problem so that I can prevent this sort of type conversion error in the future, or just a better way to code this general logic.

If it matters, I'm in Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Any help (anti-inflammatory wisdom) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does the method want `IComparable` implementers anyway? There is no need..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a generic [where clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) you would define it as follows:

```
public static void PrintKeyValuePairs<T, U>(Dictionary<T, U> dict)
        where T : IComparable
        where U : IComparable
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<T, U> item in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        }

    }
```

calling it with a `Dictionary<string, int>` has no error:

```
PrintKeyValuePairs(new Dictionary<string, int> { { "duck", 4 }, { "goose", 5 } });
```

Comment: When I originally tried that I had "PrintKeyValuePairs<T, T>(Dictionary<IComparable, IComparable>) and I left off the "where" segments. Looks like I still have a lot to learn.. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @SteveTheCoder In your current implementation all you require is that the object has a ToString() implementation which does not require IComparable.  You actually don't need the where clause in this case unless adding some other functionality not noted.